Xamarin Forms DataGrid showing selected data row in textboxes
I have this dg:DataGrid which is a good free option for showing data. My following code doesn't show an error, but it doesn't do anything, and exit the app.
    <dg:DataGrid x:Name="GridConten" SelectionEnabled="True" 
     RowHeight="43" HeaderHeight="50" BorderColor="WHITE" HeaderBackground="#a7dae8"                    
    WidthRequest="1800" PullToRefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}"
     ActiveRowColor="#ebab34" ItemSelected="GridConten_ItemSelected">

    <dg:DataGrid.Columns>
                    <dg:DataGridColumn Title="ID" PropertyName="idCal" Width="100"></dg:DataGridColumn>
                    <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Name" PropertyName="name" Width="100"></dg:DataGridColumn>
                    <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Color" PropertyName="color" Width="100"></dg:DataGridColumn>
                    <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Size" PropertyName="size" Width="100"></dg:DataGridColumn>
                </dg:DataGrid.Columns>
    <dg:DataGrid.RowsBackgroundColorPalette>
        <dg:PaletteCollection>
                    <Color>WHITE</Color>
                    <Color>#fcf6de</Color>
        </dg:PaletteCollection>
    </dg:DataGrid.RowsBackgroundColorPalette>
</dg:DataGrid>

Code behind
How I fill the DataGrid
var prod = await App.SQLiteDB.GetProductsAsync(idcat);
GridConten.ItemsSource = prod;

The DataGrid shows the data very well. But I had a ListView in other app and I took first row cell value with this sentence.
var obj = (Products)e.SelectedItem;
var prod = await App.SQLiteDB.GetProductsByAsync(obj.idcat) ;

So now I use this sentence instead this: "var obj = (Products)e.SelectedItem;" to obtain the row values.
var obj = (Products)e.CurrentSelection;
var prod = await App.SQLiteDB.GetProductsByAsync(obj.idcat) ;

It doesn't do anything, no issues or error.
I only want to select a row and the first value of the cell.
Thanks.
